# Div with background image and centered content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to make a div with background image of unknown size. Inside this div I need some content in the middle.

The problem is that I don't know the background image size.

I've found 2 solutions but I can't get it work together.
First, how to automatically adjust div width/height ad its background:

```
<div style="background:url(...); background-size: contain;">
    <img src="the_same_url" style="visilibity: hidden;">
</div>
```

Second how to vertically align [How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

And also the content should be wrapped in wrapper (width: 960px; margin: 0 auto); I cannot get it work together at all =\

So basically this thing is needed in order to create a block with some big background which will take 100% width of site and in the center there will be some content. But the size of this block will depend on background image

Also I can use jQuery but I can't figure out how

Comment: 2 questions : 1) the div containing the image must be the size of the image or be 100% width of window? 2) Do you realy need th image to be in the background? or can it be a `<img>` tag?

Comment: 1. Well, basically I need an image covering full site width. I don't know actually, I guess 100% of window 2. No, it can be img tag. You propose use absolute position?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Dj7Hb/

Comment: or probably this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Dj7Hb/1/

Comment: But here you set 100% width and height of the body, but I don't know height or width. Like your first example but image there is several such blocks, what would you do?

Comment: You are going to have to be more precise about the layout you are trying to achieve. If you have several blocks, you can do this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Dj7Hb/3/

Comment: I'll draw it, wait a second

Comment: http://themeforest.net/item/binder-corporate-html5-template/full_screen_preview/7648563 like here where WE LEAD THE WAY label is placed. Or BEST STUFF. But they set fixed height and also move background image, and I want to just put bg image as it is. BG image should have 100% width and corresponding height (takes ratio into account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `position:absolute;` and `display:table`/`display:table-cell;`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Dj7Hb/7/)**

*HTML:*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="YOUR_IMAGE" />
    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <div>
                 blahblab
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
.wrapper > img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.content {
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.content > div {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.content > div > div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your situation completely but would this work?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="background">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

#background {
    background: #ddd url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#background img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's the pen: http://codepen.io/andyngo/pen/seanA